# Laravel - Query multiple objects to filter records by

Tags: laravel

I have a filter menu on the front end each which queries records based on a column filter which filters these records based on a column, operator and value entered. What I would like to do is pass an array of objects through to my API and filter by the number of filters applied from the frontend.

Example filter:

```
"{"fromDate":"","toDate":"","column":"date","operator":"=","value":"Rent"}"
```

Code to query filters:

```
return TransactionResource::collection(Transaction::query()
                ->when($filters->column !== 'date', function ($query) use ($filters) {
                    $query->where($filters->column, $filters->value);
                })
                ->when($filters->column === 'date', function ($query) use ($filters) {
                    $query->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::parse($filters->fromDate)->format('Y-m-d'), Carbon::parse($filters->toDate)->format('Y-m-d')]);
                })->paginate($pageLimit))->response();
```

What I would ideally like to do is pass in an array of filters as shown below, and loop through each object querying record by the filters applied.

```
"[
{"fromDate":"","toDate":"","column":"date","operator":"=","value":"Rent"},
{"fromDate":"2021-01-01","toDate":"2021-01-10","column":"date","operator":"","value":""}
]"
```

I've tried wrapping the query in a foreach loop without any luck, which doesn't work. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how I might accomplish this.

Looping through - no records are returned

```
            foreach($filters as $filter) {
                TransactionResource::collection(
                    Transaction::query()
                    ->when($filter->column !== 'date', function ($query) use ($filter) {
                        $query->where($filter->column, $filter->value);
                    })
                    ->when($filter->column === 'date', function ($query) use ($filter) {
                        $query->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::parse($filter->fromDate)->format('Y-m-d'), Carbon::parse($filter->toDate)->format('Y-m-d')]);
                    })->paginate($pageLimit))->response();
            }
```

Comment: Did you get any errors? If Yes add an error in the question will help someone to answer your question.

Comment: No errors, just all data was returned. Have updated OP.

Comment: Scratch that - no records get returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be using `when` here since you can easily use `if` and `else` statements since you are looping:

```
$query = Transaction::query();

foreach ($filters as $filter) {
    if ($filter->column == 'date') {
        $query->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::parse($filter->fromDate)->format('Y-m-d'), Carbon::parse($filter->toDate)->format('Y-m-d')]);
    } else {
        $query->where($filter->column, $filter->operator ?? '=', $filter->value);
    }
}

return TransactionResource::collection($query->paginate(...));
```

Side note: when using `when` it can take 2 callbacks. The first is the one that is executed when the condition is true, the second is the one that is executed when the condition is false. So if you just need a 'if/else' you can do it with one `when` call.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for - it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Change `response()` to `get()` then above will work.